# Obtener ventana en Linux por coordenadas (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, linux

Quisiera si alguien me puede decir si existe alguna forma de obtener la información de una ventana que existe en el escritorio dadas unas determinadas coordenadas.

Es decir, si existe una alternativa a la función "WindowFromPoint" de Windows pero para Linux, más especificamente LinuxMint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontré una solución utilizando la función XQueryPointer().

Siguiendo el ejemplo que encontré en este [enlace](https://homepage.boetes.org/software/xquerypointer.c).

La ventana buscada se encuentra en la variable **ret_child**.

El código del enlace es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Gave a warning.
    // unsigned int snooze_time = 100000;
    Display *dpy;
    Window root;
    Window ret_root;
    Window ret_child;
    int root_x;
    int root_y;
    int win_x;
    int win_y;
    unsigned int mask;

    dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    root = XDefaultRootWindow(dpy);

    if(XQueryPointer(dpy, root, &ret_root, &ret_child, &root_x, &root_y,
                     &win_x, &win_y, &mask))
    {   
        // original version
        //    printf("root loc: %4d,%4d win loc: %3d,%3d mask: 0x%08X\n",
        //           root_x, root_y, win_x, win_y, mask);

        // This returns in -geometry format
        // I added \n so it actually shows something so people who test it know it works.
        printf("+%d+%d\n", root_x, root_y);
    }
    else
    {
        // your script will break with this output, send it to stderr and let the script
        // return something sensible like +10+10 
        printf("hmmmm, where is that sneaky pointer?\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No respondas con un enlace... pon el código correspondiente. El enlace puede dejar de estar disponible en cualquier momento... mientras que el código no tiene ese problema

Answer (score 0):

Buscando un poquito por Internet puedes llegar a [este enlace](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getparyx), donde te cuentan que tienes a tu disposición una serie de funciones para tal menester:

- `getyx`: Cooordenadas del cursor en la ventana pasada como parámetro
- `getparyx`: Coordenadas de la ventana andidada respecto a la ventana padre.
- `getbegyx`: Coordenadas de la ventana.
- `getmaxyx`: Tamaño de la ventana.

No has puesto ningún ejemplo de código así que no queda claro si ya tienes el puntero a la ventana o si (por alguna mala coincidencia) estas funciones no resultan útiles en tu caso.